# StringRegExp pattern not working properly

Tags: arrays, string, autoit, pcre

I have this string:

```
{"name": "Fancy HaXXor123Name","profession": 1,"race": 2,"map_id": 1052,"world_id": 268435461,"team_color_id": 0,"commander": false,"fov": 0.768}
```

I want to get an array back which includes the following information (from left to right from the string):

```
Fancy HaXXor123Name
1
2
1052
268435461
0
false
0.768
```

I tried to mess with RegExBuddy and got a promissing pattern which looks like this

```
(\d{1,}).(\d{1,})|(\d{1,})|(?i)"(.*?)"
```

This is what I got back

```
name



Fancy HaXXor123Name



profession


1



race


2



map_id
10
2



world_id
2684354
1



team_color_id


0



commander



fov
0
768
```

So there are large spaces between the informations, torn numbers and the false is missing. I can't fix this problem and I'm completely new to StringRegExp.

I'm using AutoIT which uses the PCRE RegExp-Engine (this is what think).

Comment: That looks like JSON, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex like the following:

```
"\s*:\s*(?:"\K[^"]*|\K[^][\s,{}]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LYXK6N/1)

**Details**:

- `"\s*:\s*` - a literal `"`, 0+ whitespaces, `:`, 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:"\K[^"]*|\K[^][\s,{}]+)` - A non-capturing group matching 2 alternatives:

  - `"\K[^"]*` - a `"`, then `\K` zeros the text matched so far, and then matches 0+ chars other than  `"` with `[^"]*`
  - `\K[^][\s,{}]+` - `\K` drops the text matched so far, and `[^][\s,{}]+` matches 1+ chars other than `]`, `[`, whitespace, `,`, `{` and `}`.